# ATMega1284 and Relative Humidity libraries

Tags: sensors

I am trying to use some Relative Humidity sensors (DHT11 and DHT22) with the ATMega1284 processor on a breadboard. I use libraries from Arduino playground (dht.h), Adafruit (DHT.h) and others. Even though both sensors and libraries work fine with Arduino Uno and Mega, they fail with ATMega1284, which produces an INVALID_VALUE error.

Connections are double checked, and other libraries such as Wire, OneWire etc work fine.

Does anyone have any experience with the ATMega1284 processor, or any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try reading the libraries to see if they special case on the '328P and/or '1280?

Comment: Actually I did, but they looked quite simple, no definitions of processors there.

Comment: Are you sure you have your pin assignments correct?  The 1284 has a few different pin assignments as it isn't a standard Arduino board.  I haven't had any issues using the DHT22 with the Mighty1284 setup.

Comment: What pins are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Per the library instructions, you will receive `INVALID_VALUE` in the following situations:

> The `readXX()` functions return:
>
> - `DHTLIB_OK` (0) : if the sensor sample and its checksum is OK.
> - `DHTLIB_ERROR_CHECKSUM` (-1) : if the checksum test failed. This means that data was received but may be incorrect.
> - `DHTLIB_ERROR_TIMEOUT` (-2) : if a timeout occured, communication failed.
>
> In case of a `DHTLIB_ERROR_TIMEOUT`, humidity and temperature will both get the value `DHTLIB_INVALID_VALUE`. In case of `DHTLIB_ERROR_CHECKSUM` the values of humidity and temperature are left unchanged as it is impossible to determine which byte failed in the checksum. It is up to the programmer to decide what to do. One can compare with previous value, but better reread the sensor.

So read the value returned by the `read11()` or `read22()` functions to verify that it's an `DHTLIB_ERROR_TIMEOUT` condition, and if so try to figure out why the library is having trouble talking to the device.

Comment: It is a DHTLIB_ERROR_TIMEOUT (-2), but I can not understand the reason.